# Is it possible to set MDCCollectionViewCell from Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, swift, material-components

From the demo apps I see all of the projects set MDCCollectionViewCell from codes and make no use of the autolayout to constraint the subviews, is it the only way now?

Comment: What is it? Open source component?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible to use custom cells created in a storyboard in the normal way in an [MDCCollectionView](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/tree/develop/components/Collections). I just modified the [`Collections > Storyboard Example`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/blob/develop/components/Collections/examples/CollectionsStoryboardExample.m) to use a custom cell defined in the associated storyboard. The cell has a customized label with italic text and a light blue background. It's not pretty, but it gets the idea across. :)

Does that answer your question?